# ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: 'Operation Date'

Tags: python, csv, datetime

New to Python. This probably might be a Python-specific question rather than related to the datetime library. I'm trying to cast a string value, which is in ISO 8601 format, to a date object. However, I keep getting the following error:

```bash
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data 'Operation Date' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
```

Don't even know what 'Operation Date' means.
here is the code:

```py
with open('ledger.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
  reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

  for row in reader:
    datetime.strptime("2024-01-02T06:39:27.000Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ") #OK
    datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ") #ERROR!
  csv_file.close()
```

Note that the first line in the loop works fine. However, the second line throws an error

Here's the CSV row format in my ledger.csv file:

```
2023-12-22T22:14:46.000Z,MATIC,NFT_IN,....
2023-12-22T22:12:55.000Z,MATIC,NFT_IN,......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes when parsing the column headers of the CSV file. When using the default csv reader, the column headers are also considered as a normal row. You can use `DictReader` instead.

```
with open('ledger.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in reader:
        datetime.strptime(row['Operation Date'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```